# return a key from within all associative array items with mongodb and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I get all the keys from within an associative array in a mongodb collection using 
the PHP driver.

**Document:**

```
[_id] => 1
[campaigns] => Array (
    [4e3b924d18153] => Array (
        [name] => Campaign One,
        [flag] => 1,
    ),
    [4e3b924d18154] => Array (
        [name] => Campaign Two,
        [flag] => 1,
    ),
    [4e3b924d18155] => Array (
        [name] => Campaign Three,
    ),
)
```

I need to get any **flag** fields from within the associative array **campaigns**.
Flag may not necessarily exist.

Basically, I want to know which campaigns have the **flag** set.

I can use the following query, but it will return only the flag key for the first campaign

```
array('_id' => array('$in' => $projectIds)), array('campaigns.0.flag')
```

I would like to return the **flag** index for any campaign that is exists in.

Comment: [$exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to do that with php the following lines should help you:

```
$flaged_compaigns = array();
foreach ($campaigns as $compaign->$data) {
    if (isset($data['flag']) and $data['flag']) {
        $flaged_compaigns[$compaign] = $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when run query in db.
Init mongo and get your collection.
Run find with the following conditions:

```
array('_id' => array('$in' => $projectIds), 'flag' => array('$exists' => true)).
```

One drawback you can't use index by this field 'flag' in exists in versions 1.8.x or older.
See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists .

Comment: This query only seems to work if I replace flag with 'campaigns.4e3b924d18153.flag' -- and this obviously only searches that one array.  How can I check for existence in any of the campaign arrays?

Comment: As I understand you get all records which contain flag field. If so you can use my solution. if not give some explanation or examples.